# $\operatorname{Hom}_B(M\otimes_A B, B) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A) \otimes_A B$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $M$ be a finitely generated projective $A$-module. Then is it true that $$\operatorname{Hom}_B(M\otimes_A B, B) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A) \otimes_A B$$

as $B$-modules?

My attempt: I can show that the result is true for $M=A^n$. For the general case, I tried as follows: There exists an $A$-module $N$ such that $M\oplus N = A^n$ for some $n$. So, we have the isomorphism
$$\operatorname{Hom}_B(M\otimes_A B, B)\oplus \operatorname{Hom}_B(N\otimes_A B, B) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A) \otimes_A B \oplus \operatorname{Hom}_A(N,A) \otimes_A B $$

But I couldn't show that the isomorphism restricted to $\operatorname{Hom}_B(M\otimes_A B, B)$ maps into $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A) \otimes_A B$.

Comment: If $M$ is locally trivial in the following sense: There is a finite open cover $D(f_i)$ of $S:=Spec(A)$ with $A_{f_i}\otimes_A M \cong A_{f_i}^n$, it follows you may localize and use your observation that it holds for $M=A^n$. There is a relation between projective modules and locally trivial  modules (in Matsumura, page 52). If $M$ is of finite presentation then $M$ is projective iff $M_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is free for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A$. (Mat.Thm.7.12). When $M$ is finitely generated, $M$ is locally trivial iff $M_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is free for any maximal ideal.